# How to determine values of coefficients for a comparisonx using factorial design?

Tags: statistics, statistical-mechanics

I think my problem is best answered by answering the following example but the more general the answer and explanation the better:

Given 2 factors X and Y, x with 2 levels x1 x2 and Y with three factors y1 y2 y3 how would one set up the coefficients for the contrasts for the mean, the levels of the 2 factors and the interactions between the levels (x1 X y2 for example) if I wanted to compare the average of the x factors given y2 and to the average of y2 and y3 given x1.

This is related to a HMK question (not the same set up) I have where I need to fill out a chart for different comparisons that would like this for the given problem.

```
Term     | Mean |   x   |     y     |     A*B          | Divisor (if needed)
Level    |  u   | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |x1Xy1 | x1Xy2 ... |
Contrast |      |   |   |   |   |   |      |           |
```